# Vector subscript out of range when searching for a string

Tags: c++, vector

I am opening a file and reading in a list of 10k names. Once I have that placed into an array (names[]), I then need to search through the array, and see if names match an entered string, and if so, I then need to place those matches into a vector (vsFirst). This is pretty easy, but I am getting a vector subscript out of range. Here's my code for this portion:

```
bool NameSearch::FindLastNames(vector<string> &vsFirst, string n)
{
    name = n;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        string holder = names[i];
        string find = name;
        cout << holder;
        int index = holder.find_first_of(",");
        if ((holder.rfind(find, index)) && holder.rfind(find, index)<=  holder.length())
        {
            cout << "it was found";
            vsFirst.push_back(holder);
            bReady = true;
        }
    }
    return bReady;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I've run some tests and it doesn't look like it's even making it into the for loop. My call to the function is:

```
vector<string> lastNames;


nSearch.FindLastNames(lastNames, searchTerm);
```

All names in the array are of the form lastname, firstname. I know the array is getting loaded with the names.

Help? Thank you!

Comment: Where is `names` defined? Not a global variable I hope. Also your code is inefficient - it makes a lot of string copies. You may want to clear `vsFirst` in case a reused vector is passed to your function (depending on what behavior you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if substring is found or not you need to compare with `std::string::npos`

change

```
if ((holder.rfind(find, index)) && holder.rfind(find, index)
```

to

```
if (holder.rfind(find, index) != std::string::npos && holder.rfind(find, index) != std::string::npos)
```